# HTML Agility Pack cells merged

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to pull a table off of a website using the HTML Agility Pack. I'm having a problem extracting the column data.  Each row should have 6 columns.  However when I read the cells it's merging all column data into one result.

I'm getting this:
Vintage Buff Banner665c12425

Instead of this:

Vintage Buff Banner

665c

1

24

Blank

25

Code I'm using is below:

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.tf2wh.com/backpack?bp=x44rUEmREP-OCT9Kp-9w6n3GOJQJpf43YQD_dp98AvY");

    var xpath = "/html/body/div[@class='page']/div[@class='main']/div[@class='specialtrade']/table[@class='data']/tbody/tr[@class='normal']";

    var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
    foreach (HtmlNode row in rows)
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("th|td");
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cell: " + cell.InnerText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it was bad HTML.  I ran it through Tidy.NET before HTML Agility Pack, and I'm getting the results I want.